# Como crear bucle dentro de un switch case

Tags: arduino

lo que sucede es que quiero hacer un menú de opciones con un switch case en Arduino para manejar distintas secuencias con 2 LEDS, pero no sé cómo hacer para que se mantenga la opción, ya que al escoger un caso, solo se hará una vez y quiero hacerlo indefinidamente hasta que ingresé otra opción, agradezco su colaboración, soy nuevo programando.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, te recomiendo leer el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) las preguntas tienen que ser sobre alguna duda que tengas con un código que has creado.

Comment: Hola. agrega código para poder ayudarte mejor, la opción es manejar while(true) y luego la salida de los ciclos infinitos con break, cada que se requiera con un condicional. Agrega el código.

Comment: te recomiendo ver ejemplos de maquinas de estados para implementar lo que queres hacer, te dejo un link: https://www.luisllamas.es/maquina-de-estados-finitos-arduino/
Saludos!

Comment: Hola Alejandro, tal y como está redactada la pregunta es demasiado amplia y le falta información clave. Por favor edítala para añadir algo más de detalles, el código que lleves hasta el momento y los mensajes de error (si alguno) que estés recibiendo. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo metiendo tu switch case dentro de un bucle do while y poniendo una condición para salir del bucle, mira este ejemplo:

```
int option = 0;

do {
   printf("Selecciona una opcion del menu:\n");
   printf("Opcion 1 : 1");
   printf("Opcion 2: 2");
   printf("Salir: 3");
   printf("Opcion elegida: ");
   scanf("%d", &option);

   switch (option) {
       case 1:
           printf("Elegiste 1");
           break;
       case 2:
           printf("Elegiste 2");
           break;
   }
} while (option != 3);
```